# Replace image src tag from string- ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am trying to replace src tag for images from src. and i also need to save images on document directory .
I have tried following code. but no luck .

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex =[NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(<img\\s[\\s\\S]*?src\\s*?=\\s*?['\"](.*?)['\"][\\s\\S]*?>)+?" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
[regex enumerateMatchesInString:str_TotalString
options:0
range:NSMakeRange(0, [str_TotalString length])
usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL stop) {
NSString *img=[str_TotalString substringWithRange:[result rangeAtIndex:2]];
NSLog(@"img src %@",img);
NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:str_TotalString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [str_TotalString length])];
if (abc==0)
{
[self saveTODOC:img:0];
}
else
{
[self saveTODOC:img:abc];
}
str_TotalString=[str_TotalString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:img withString:imgHTMLTag_Replace];
NSLog(@"Found %lu",(unsigned long)numberOfMatches);
}];
```

any help please

Comment: Your code is unclear. `[saveToDoc:omg:0]` that seems to use a method not respecting at all naming conventions. Do you have a sample for `str_TotalString`?

Comment: str_TotalString contains html str. this is dynamic str.  i need to download all images from that string . and replace with local document directory path. so i can use it in offline mode